# Wordpress local site switching to live URL

Tags: wordpress, url, wamp, http-status-code-302

I am trying to install an existing wordpress site on my local machine
Ive set up database and site, but the issue Im having is when I hit the site on my local machine at url mysite.local it resolves to the live site mysite.com

What IVe done:

changed the URL of site_url and home in the options table in db
turned off all plugins
searched and replaced any hardcoded url in code (there were many!) and replaced with `site_url()`

Ive even noticed that when I call the site and it resolves to live URL the site_url and home values in options table are getting re-written with the live URL

Im not at all familiar with WP so Im wondering if Im missing something obvious or if anyone has run into similar issues

when the page is called IVe noticed that it sets a 302 permanently moved header

any ideas?

Comment: as a workaround you can try to use hosts file and put there mysite.com pointing to your localhost: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all occurrences in the database are replaced. You can use the below SQL

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://oldsite', 'http://newsite') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://oldsite', 'http://newsite');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://oldsite', 'http://newsite');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://oldsite', 'http://newsite');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with htaccess to see if the live url is encoded in to redirect to that when you hit the directory to resolve anything like index.php or index.html. This usually is the first culprit in redirection.

Check if there is a cache plugin installed which i think you would have done already.

I think the next steps you have done are alright and options table would be one to confirm that it has written data to table.

Answer (score 0):

For others with redirect problems on local WordPress install...

I made this repository: https://github.com/lumonald/existing-wordpress-development-docker

You can quickly get a pre-existing WP site up and running locally.